# I don't understand this infini-loop

Tags: c++, while-loop

I'm sorry if this seems very simple to fix, but I encountered something odd when doing what should've been a simple while loop. Can anyone help me remedy why this loop goes on forever?

This code was desgined for this simple drill:

> There is an old story that the emperor wanted to thank the inventor of
>   the game of chess and asked the inventor to name his reward. The
>   inventor asked for **one grain of rice for the first square, 2 for the
>   second, 4 for the third, and so on, doubling for each of the 64
>   squares.** That may sound modest, but there wasn’t that much rice in
>   the empire! Write a program to calculate
>   **how many squares are required to give the inventor at least 1000 grains of rice, at least 1,000,000 grains, and at least 1,000,000,000
>   grains.** You’ll need a loop, of course, and probably an int to keep
>   track of which square you are at, an int to keep the number of grains
>   on the current square, and an int to keep track of the grains on all
>   previous squares. We suggest that you write out the value of all your
>   variables for each iteration of the loop so that you can see what’s
>   going on.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  double square = 2;
  double rice = 2;
  while (rice < 1000000000, rice *= 2)
  {
    cout << "There is " << rice << " pieces of rice that the inventor owns at square " 
         << square << endl;
    cout << "\n";
    square++;
  }
}
```

If this makes any difference, I rewrote this code to fit into java and got the same thing on eclipse.

Comment: You probably wanted `while (rice *= 2, rice < 1000000000)` instead of `while (rice < 1000000000, rice *= 2)`

Comment: Java doesn't have a comma operator, so you can't have had exactly this code in Java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> while (rice < 1000000000, rice *= 2)
> ```

This is an application of the [**comma operator**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator)!

Its meaning here is:

- Evaluate the left part, `rice < 1000000000`, with all side effects.
- There are no side effects in `rice < 1000000000`.
- **Discard** the evaluation result of the left part (i.e. throw away the resulting `true` or `false`).
- Evalulate the right part, `rice *= 2`, with all side effects.
- The side effect is that `rice` is multiplied by 2.
- Treat the resulting `rice` as a `bool`. `rice` is an `int`, so every value other than 0 is considered `true`. The result of `rice *= 2` is therefore always `true`.
- The result of the entire comma operator is the **result of the right part**, i.e. `true`.

So, the problem is that your loop condition is *always* `true`.

(If that's confusing for you, rest assured that the comma operator does have its uses in C++, but they tend to be rare.)

One possible fix for your program would be:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  double square = 2;
  double rice = 2;
  while (rice < 1000000000)
  {
    rice *= 2;
    cout << "There is " << rice << " pieces of rice that the inventor owns at square " 
         << square << endl;
    cout << "\n";
    square++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in `while (rice < 1000000000, rice *= 2)` condition. If several statements are divided by comma, the result of whole statement equals to the result of the last one. So you actually have `while (rice *= 2)` that will be definitely true.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a comma operator inside the while expression.

Don't do it.

Conditional expressions in loops should always be simple and easy to read, and should have no side effects. A comma operator removes this simplicity, adds unnecessary complexity and is error prone, as your question demonstrates.

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
while (rice < 1000000000, rice *= 2)
```

This doesn't do what you probably think it does. The while loop doesn't have an increment part, so this is a comma-expression, where the first part is evaluated and then discarded, and the second part (the multiplication) is the actual result. This means that the result is the new value of `rice`, converted to boolean, which is always going to be true unless overflow happens to hit 0 at some point.

What you want is

```
for (; rice < 1000000000; rice *= 2)
```

Comment: Oh, okay. I haven't dealt into too many problems involving while loops before to understand how this worked. In what situation would I use the comma operator where I would discard something in this manner?

Comment: @Episha You very rarely need the comma operator. The most common use is in the third part of a for loop header, if you want to do two things, e.g. `for (...; ...; ++i, ++j)`.

Comment: Ah, I never heard of a comma operator until this question, and I've read into my C++ book and didn't see anything about it.

Comment: Regarding your last line of code: Why not even `for (double rice = 2; rice < 1000000000; rice *= 2)`?

Comment: I'm not too sure of the question but if it's as to why I didn't use a for, it's mainly because I didn't feel to confident doing a for loop as I am with whiles. Which led to this irony.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Because I didn't look closely enough at the question to see if that was the right thing.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a composite expression in your while, as though it's a "for"

```
while( rice < 1000000000, rice *= 2)
```

the truth value is the second of the two expressions separated by the comma

```
rice *= 2
```

is a non-zero value and hence is true

Either

```
while ( rice < 1000000000) {

      /...
      rice *=2;
}
```

or use a for, where the semi-colon does what you are expecting

```
for ( rice = 2; rice < 10000000; rice *= 2 ) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use for loop to calculate how many squares are required.

```
int main ()
{
    int grain = 1 ;

    for (int i = 2; i < 65 ; ++i)   // iteration for each of the 64 squares, starting from square 2
    {
        grain += grain ;            // doubling for each of the 64 squares

       if (grain > 1000 && grain < 2000)                // at least 1000 grains of rice
        {
            cout << "square is: " << i << " grains is: " << grain << '\n' ;
        }

        if (grain > 1000000 && grain < 2000000)         // at least 1,000,000 grains
        {
            cout << "square is: " << i << " grains is: " << grain << '\n' ;
        }
        if (grain > 1000000000 && grain < 2000000000)   //at least 1,000,000,000 grains
        {
            cout << "square is: " << i << " grains is: " << grain << '\n' ;
        }
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: What's the point of `square` (misspelt) if it just equals `i`? Why do you duplicate all those `cout`s if you're still repeating them thousands/millions of times? Where in this is the question answered? Hmm...

Comment: the game of chess contains 64 squares you need to start with value 1 on first square and doubling this value for each of 64 squares

Comment: Yes I read the question. You didn't address my comment. Not sure what the value of this new submission is to be honest.

Comment: thank you for your comments. I have modified my code and removed the optional square variable, using only i to represent square.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a super old question, but I've just started with the book and this was my solution:

```
#include "../../std_lib_facilities.h"

int main() {
  int current_square = 1;
  int rice_amount = 1;
  int user_desired_amount = 0;

  cout<<"Enter amount of rice you want to get the number of squares needed: \n";
  cin>>user_desired_amount;

  while(rice_amount <= user_desired_amount) {
    rice_amount *= 2;
    cout<<"rice_amount: "<<rice_amount<<"\n";
    current_square++;
  }
  cout<<"Needed squares are: "<<current_square<<"\n";
  
  return 0;
}
```

Didn't make use of fixed number to get a limit in order to test how the code responded to different inputs. I would love to have anyone inputs if you think this is a bad approach. Thanks in advance!

Comment: That would be better to use `Camel Case Naming Convention` for naming your variables and functions; It makes your code, `clean code`

Comment: Thank you! I was using the snake_case cuz that's the way that the examples appear in the book, but i agree with you totally.